# CRUD Razor Scaffolded Page is not styled

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

After I created my entity models and I generated migrations, I made CRUD scaffolding for one of the entities, but the pages were not styled at all, and all the links weren't working, I added the following

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

which only added the links and added names next to the fields [Product Index Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSOOF.png)

My product model is also associated with a model called Category which is a required field but in the create or edit pages the option to add a category foriegn key isn't available

[Product Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlRbf.png)

How do I fix the styling problem? and is there a reason the foriegn key relation fields weren't generated, although they are generated correctly in DB?

Comment: How did you generate the scaffolded pages? If you used the command line, you must include the `-udl` switch to set the layout which is responsible for styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the pages were not styled at all, and all the links weren't working

Based on your description, If don't set up a layout, it may result in a page structure that isn't shared.You can check if you set layout when you use scaffolding and make sure the layout is configured correctly. If Still can't see the style of the page, You can provide relevant error messages in the developer tools.[image]

> the option to add a category foriegn key isn't available.

About this problem do you want to add an item to the page that can be set as a category to add and edit related products? You can provide more detailed model code and problem descriptions to help you better.

Comment: Thank you this worked, but all links are still not functional. the Product model is this: 

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProdName { get; set; }
    [Required]  
    public float Price { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public Category category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Supplier supplier { get; set; }

    
    public List<Review> reviews { get; set; }

    public List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCarts { get; set; }

    public List<Order> orders { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Typically, navigation properties are used in entity classes to represent relationships between entities, rather than to store raw data. In this Product entity, you can use the CategoryId property as a foreign key property, which is used to store the foreign key value associated with the Category entity. Instead of adding on the Category navigation property, you can apply the [Required] attribute on the CategoryId to ensure that the attribute is not null when the model is validated. You could create a new thread if you encounter any further problems.